# How i can set instance variable using mass assignment in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :notify
 end

User.new(args)
```

What I'm doing:

```
User.new(args)
User.notify = true
```

What I need is something like:

```
User.new(args.merge(:notify => true))
```

Comment: what is `args` in your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have shown will work.  Make sure to include `:notify` in the list of attributes for `attr_accessible` if you are using that.

Comment: `:attr_accessible` was removed in Rails 4

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the `attr_accessor` defined, including the variable in any ActiveRecord mass assignment will work. As "Wizard of Ogz" mentioned, limiting access to the attributes affects both database attributes and instance variables alike.

Comment: yes - limiting access affects instance varaible too. i missed it